# Software-based training on Linux

Tags: learning, software, training

10 years ago I used to learn from an old version of Fritz on DVD. It was great. It had a teaching move while you played full games and it also had automated curriculum to teach you openings, endings, and tactics.

At this point in my life I've fully rejected all Windows and MacOS operating systems in favor of Linux. I'd like to have a chess learning experience like I did with Fritz, though.

I've signed up for Chessbase/Fritz online, but it doesn't seem to have any of the many learning features that I had a decade ago. Do I have any other good options?

I'm looking for a richer learning experience than just an engine analyzing my games post-hoc.

Comment: What about Wine?

Comment: @SmallChess Theoretically, yes, that would solve the problem. Practically speaking I find that the effects on performance and stability usually cause me a big headache.

Comment: If you really have to use computer then buy a .PDF on the topic of your interest, open whichever chessboard, read the book and play the moves. If you want to learn, analyze your own games, don't waste time on chess software. In my opinion chess software is good only for preparation and to check if all the lines of your tactics were well-calculated.

Comment: What about an android emulator? There are numerous training apps in the Google Play store.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Alright, perhaps you and SmallChess can flush out your emulation answers and I will upvote both and accept one.

Comment: @SmallChess Please see my comment to HerbWolfe above. I was hoping for something native, but it looks like we are going to need to roll with emulation.

Comment: @Hack-R I am curious about this question, did you find anything worth mentioning?

Comment: Not sure the question is actual any more but feel free to check Alien Chess, very new app for Android. Yes, it's my application :D And it has quite some training functions.

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at [lichess.org](http://lichess.org) ? It has a solid web interface, Android/iPhone applications, plenty of chess games/variants, analysis move, there are a few trainings, starting from the basics and ending with pretty advanced stuff, finally there are puzzles taken from the actual chess games, where you have to win the game someone won (or lost) before.

Comment: I <3 lichess. Even spoke to the developer on Github before :)  but better for playing than training.

Comment: @Hack-R if you can tell what you want or explain the missing parts, it might get eventually implemented there =)

Comment: Sure, fair enough. I'm focusing on the part about analysis and training. As much as I am a ***huge*** lichess fan, it's actually much more basic learning in favor of being oriented towards multiplayer live games. I'm looking for something that corrects and explains mistakes, like some of the many Windows apps like Fritz and Chessmaster of the 1990's and 00's. With the MMO sites they are mostly not focused on that sort of human-to-computer learning. Chess.com and others have some things like drills, which are wonderful, but to my knowledge none of them have significant coaching features.

Comment: @Hack-R from my point of view, it's better to 100% concentrate on playing the game, then spend some time mulling over the analysis and learning from mistakes. constantly switching between "playing" and "learning" mode puts a heavy toll on my brain. but it might be just my problem =)

Comment: Sometimes I've felt that way. I've played about 50k games. But the last 50% of that didn't help my ELO. I'm friends with a chess coach but I don't want to pay even the friend rate for lessons because it adds up over time haha. So I just want to try putting 10% of my time into self-paced AI learning.

Comment: @Hack-R playing so many games can only bring your rating to 1500-1600 level, to progress beyond that you need to study. not necessarily with a coach, there are plenty of good books available, I'm sure your friend can recommend a few of them free of charge =) RE: analysis, I think lichess can do that and point where you make a mistake or blunder, and propose a better move, that might steer your thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, you're right. That's about where my rating is.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Lucas Chess](https://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/).
There's a version for both Linux and Windows. (I use the windows version with wine and no performance problems).
There's a lot of modes and resources for studying in this software.